# How to determine the state of an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to determine how to remove an instance from several applications (freeIPA, Chef, service discovery) from within an AWS autoscaling group but I'm finding that there's no reliable way to determine if an instance is simply stopping (sometimes our admins will take an instance out of the ASG for analysis) vs terminating.  If the instance is stopped then I would like to retain the ability to have it stay connected to our LDAP and other systems.  Anyone know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the instance EBS backed or using instance store? 
if instance store, you cannot really stop it (only terminate it)

Have you looked at the EC2 API (via aws-sdk maybe)? (looks like describe-instances and looking at reservations should do the trick here)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html

Comment: EBS backed.  Actually I discovered a good way to do this since I'm using ASG alarms (just run the commands when the EC2_TERMINATE alarm is fired off.  Much easier than trying to get the state from another instance and compare against what was listed in the ASG's.

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the best way for me to do this was to use the ASG alarms (specifically the EC2_TERMINATE alarm).  This effectively allows me to take no action if an instance is stopping and fire off a script if it is determined that the instance is terminating.